# My .net MAUI app works in debug mode, but "dotnet publish" doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, maui

I am in the process of migrating my Xamarin.IOS app to .NET MAUI. I was able to migrate, and so far, so good here on the simulator, but when I try to publish my .IPA file to deploy to test
flight, it doesn't work.

**- The dontet cli command that I'm using:**

dotnet publish -f net7.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 -p:CodesignKey="MY-KEY" -p: CodesignProvision="MY-PROFILE"

**- The error is this:**
ILLink : error IL1040: Failed to resolve System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess. [/Users/kaioteles/Documents/Repositorios/DataArt/ArtBinder/ArtbinderMobile/ArtBinder64/ArtBinder.csproj]
Fatal error in IL Linker
Unhandled exception. Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess
at Mono.Cecil.Mixin.CheckedResolve(TypeReference self)
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeEnum(TypeReference enum_type)
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeElementValue(TypeReference type)
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeElement(TypeReference type)
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeFixedArgument(TypeReference type)
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeNamedArgument(Collection`1& fields, Collection`1& properties)
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeNamedArguments(UInt16 count, Collection`1& fields, Collection`1& properties)
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadSecurityAttribute()
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataReader.ReadSecurityDeclarationSignature(SecurityDeclaration declaration)
at Mono.Cecil.SecurityDeclaration.<>c.b__19_0(SecurityDeclaration declaration, MetadataReader reader)
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[TItem](TItem item, Action`2 read) at Mono.Cecil.SecurityDeclaration.Resolve() at Mono.Cecil.SecurityDeclaration.get_HasSecurityAttributes() at Mono.Linker.TypeReferenceWalker.WalkSecurityAttributesTypesScopes(ISecurityDeclarationProvider securityAttributeProvider) at Mono.Linker.TypeReferenceWalker.WalkScopes(TypeDefinition typeDefinition) at Mono.Linker.TypeReferenceWalker.Process() at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.TypeReferenceMarker.MarkTypeReferences(AssemblyDefinition assembly, MarkingHelpers markingHelpers) at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly) at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly, DependencyInfo reason) at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkModule(ModuleDefinition module, DependencyInfo reason) at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference, DependencyInfo reason, Nullable`1 origin)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField(FieldDefinition field, DependencyInfo& reason, MessageOrigin& origin)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireType(TypeDefinition type, DependencyInfo& reason)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireType(TypeDefinition type, DependencyInfo& reason)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly, DependencyInfo reason)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkModule(ModuleDefinition module, DependencyInfo reason)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference, DependencyInfo reason, Nullable`1 origin) at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference, DependencyInfo reason, Nullable`1 origin)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkGenericArguments(IGenericInstance instance)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.GetOriginalType(TypeReference type, DependencyInfo reason)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference, DependencyInfo reason, Nullable`1 origin) at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkGenericArguments(IGenericInstance instance) at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.GetOriginalType(TypeReference type, DependencyInfo reason) at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference, DependencyInfo reason, Nullable`1 origin)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkGenericArguments(IGenericInstance instance)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.GetOriginalType(TypeReference type, DependencyInfo reason)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference, DependencyInfo reason, Nullable`1 origin)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField(FieldDefinition field, DependencyInfo& reason, MessageOrigin& origin)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireType(TypeDefinition type, DependencyInfo& reason)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireType(TypeDefinition type, DependencyInfo& reason)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly, DependencyInfo reason)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkModule(ModuleDefinition module, DependencyInfo reason)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMarkedPending()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run(ILogger customLogger)
at Mono.Linker.Driver.Main(String[] args)
/Users/kaioteles/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.illink.tasks/7.0.100-1.23211.1/build/Microsoft.NET.ILLink.targets(86,5): error NETSDK1144: Falha na otimização de assemblies de tamanho. A otimização pode ser desabilitada definindo a propriedade PublishTrimmed como false. [/Users/kaioteles/Documents/Repositorios/DataArt/ArtBinder/ArtbinderMobile/ArtBinder64/ArtBinder.csproj]

Im not sure what is the problem, this is the list of all my depencencies that i use:
[image]

I add this property on my csproj file: copyused

After this is in place, the published works, but my NewSoft.Json lib stops working, and I can't deserialize any JSON.

Is there a problem with some of my nugget's liberties? Or is it a parameter that is missing with my dotnet publish command?

Comment: You should skip .NET 7.0 as it is out of support in a bit over a month. So switch to .NET 8.0. Also don't use Xamarin.Essentials, use Microsoft.Maui.Essentials, it is now a NuGet package when you are on .NET 8. Also not sure if using Mono.Data.Sqlite will work, it doesn't seem to have any target frameworks that are supported in .NET core, this is Sqlite package is probably why your App doesn't build.

Comment: Also check out this GitHub issue: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/8211 there is a hint to try using `<TrimMode>copyused</TrimMode>`, but one of your libraries is using `System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess` which is no bueno.